# Summarise a dataframe based on presence of a variable/ NA: In R

Tags: r, dataframe

For a sample dataframe:

```
  df <- structure(
  list(
    country = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      .Label = c("Austria", "France", "UK"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    id = 1:10,
    region.0 = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      .Label = c("AT", "FR", "UK"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    region.1 = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L,
        5L),
      .Label = c("AT1", "AT2", "FR1", "UK1", "UK4", "UK6"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    region.2 = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, NA,
        NA),
      .Label = c("AT11", "AT21", "FR12", "FR14", "FR19"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    region.3 = structure(
      c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA,
        NA),
      .Label = c("FR121", "FR142", "FR196"),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  .Names = c("country",
             "id", "region.0", "region.1", "region.2", "region.3"),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)
```

I want to produce a summary table detailing what regional-level data for countries is available at in my df dataframe.

The regional data is available at either region.1, region.2, or region.3.  Either the data is available, or listed as 'NA'.  Thelevel at which the regional data is available is the same regardless of the 'ids' for that country.

The end result which I want in a dataframe would look like:

```
  country region.1 region.2 region.3
1 Austria      Yes      Yes       No
2  France      Yes      Yes      Yes
3      UK      Yes       No       No
```

Could anyone suggest a particular package or code to help me?

Answer (score 5):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'country', specify the columns to be compare in `.SDcols`, we loop through the columns with `lapply`, then check `if` `all` the values in the column is 'NA', then we get "No" as output or `else` get "Yes"

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) 
        "No" else "Yes") , country, .SDcols=region.1:region.3]
#    country region.1 region.2 region.3
#1: Austria      Yes      Yes       No
#2:  France      Yes      Yes      Yes
#3:      UK      Yes       No       No
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can implement the same logic after grouping by 'country' (`group_by`).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(if(all(is.na(.))) "No" 
           else "Yes"), matches("^region\\.[1-9]"))
#country region.1 region.2 region.3
#   (fctr)    (chr)    (chr)    (chr)
#1 Austria      Yes      Yes       No
#2  France      Yes      Yes      Yes
#3      UK      Yes       No       No
```